# I have an issue with printing a string

Tags: c

I'm writing a program in c to delete extra spaces,I've done all the work but when I compile, the string I want in the output doesn't appear, I think the problem is in the main function, I'll show you my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void eliminar_espacios(char oracion[100]) {
int i;
for(i=0;i!='\0';i++) {
    if(oracion[i]==' ' && (oracion[i+1]==' ' || oracion[i+1]=='\0')) {
        oracion[i]=oracion[i+1];
    }
}
 }

int contar_espacios(char oracion[100])
{
    int i,numero_espacios=0;
    for (i=0;oracion[i]!='\0';i++){
        if (oracion[i]==' '&&oracion[i+1]==' '){
            numero_espacios+=1;
        }
    }
    return(numero_espacios);
}


int main(void){
    char frase[100];
    int num_espacios;
    printf("Escribe aqui a frase:");
    gets (frase);
    num_espacios=contar_espacios(frase);
    eliminar_espacios(frase);
    printf("%s\n",frase);
    printf("%d",num_espacios);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is expected and what is the unwanted result?

Comment: I expect to print a string of letters without extra spaces and the unwanted result is that the program prints me nothing

Comment: I've modified the code, but now instead of printing the string without extra spaces it simply prints the string without any modifications

Comment: Now your code works as you expected?
P.S. 1. It is better to initialize char frase[100] = {0}
2. return is not a function, it does not need brackets

Answer (score 2):

Your eliminar_espacios function has no 'return'.
Also you should use strcpy or strncopy to save new string in 'frase2',
for example:

```
strncpy(frase2, eliminar_espacios(frase), sizeof frase2)
```

Comment: I add the return and is the same. Is there any solution without using strcpy or strncopy?

Comment: @AndresOtero Is there any reason you do not want to use `strcpy` or `strncpy`?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use these functions

Comment: You need no return in the eliminar_espacios  function, cuz you are changing external char array by ref.
Do char 'eliminar_espacios(char * oracion)' prototype
and use frase to print result after calling

Comment: @AndresOtero Why on earth are you not allowed to use these functions ?!?

Comment: Conditions of my superiors

Comment: Advanced superiors))))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
strncpy(frase2, frase, 100);
frase2[99] = '\0';
eliminar_espacios(frase2);
num_espacios=contar_espacios(frase2);
```

Edit: If you want, you can get rid of frase2 entirely, just call all the functions with frase and no strcpy needed:

```
eliminar_espacios(frase);
num_espacios=contar_espacios(frase);
printf("%s\n",frase);
```

Edit2: Fix your eliminar_espacios() function:

```
void eliminar_espacios(char oracion[100]) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;oracion[i]!='\0';i++) {
        if(oracion[i]==' ' && (oracion[i+1]==' ' || oracion[i+1]=='\0')) {
            oracion[i]=oracion[i+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now it prints something!!! but it doesn't do the function of eliminar_espacios

Comment: I've tried, but when I compile the result is the same as frase, it doesn't modified it. I'll modified the main post with the new code